# How to convert xml file to HashMap using apache Tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

In my case i am able to read the xml file and parse it to get content as of meta data only provides the type of file which is "application/xml"

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.xml.XMLParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;  
public class XmlParserExample {   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {  
         BodyContentHandler handler   = new BodyContentHandler();  
         XMLParser parser             = new XMLParser();  
         Metadata metadata            = new Metadata();  
         ParseContext pcontext        = new ParseContext();  
         FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("example.xml"));
         parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);
         System.out.println("Contents of the document:" + handler.toString());
         System.out.println("Metadata of the document:");
         String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

         for(String name : metadataNames) {
            System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
         }
    }  
}
```

Above snippet of code prints the whole xml content and Content Type (as metadata).But i also want to fetch the xml tags as well so that i can create a HashMap which is requirement in my case.
Below is my Dummy example.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE PubmedArticleSet SYSTEM "http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/ncbi/pubmed/out/pubmed_190101.dtd">
<PubmedArticleSet>
  <PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
      <PMID Version="1">27483086</PMID>
      <DateCompleted>
        <Year>2018</Year>
        <Month>05</Month>
        <Day>02</Day>
      </DateCompleted>
      <DateRevised>
        <Year>2018</Year>
        <Month>05</Month>
        <Day>02</Day>
      </DateRevised>
      <Article PubModel="Print-Electronic">
        <Journal>
          <ISSN IssnType="Electronic">1532-849X</ISSN>
          <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Internet">
            <Volume>26</Volume>
            <Issue>4</Issue>
            <PubDate>
              <Year>2017</Year>
              <Month>Jun</Month>
            </PubDate>
          </JournalIssue>
          <Title>Journal of prosthodontics : official journal of the American College of Prosthodontists</Title>
          <ISOAbbreviation>J Prosthodont</ISOAbbreviation>
        </Journal>
        <ArticleTitle>The Use of CADCAM Technology for Fabricating Cast Gold Survey Crowns under Existing Partial Removable Dental Prosthesis. A Clinical Report.</ArticleTitle>
        <Pagination>
          <MedlinePgn>321-326</MedlinePgn>
        </Pagination>
        <ELocationID EIdType="doi" ValidYN="Y">10.1111jopr.12525</ELocationID>
        <Abstract>
          <AbstractText>The fabrication of a survey crown under an existing partial removable dental prosthesis (PRDP) has always been a challenge to many dental practitioners. This clinical report presents a technique for fabricating accurate cast gold survey crowns to fit existing PRDPs using CAD/CAM technology. The report describes a technique that would digitally scan the coronal anatomy of a cast gold survey crown and an abutment tooth under existing PRDPs planned for restoration, prior to any preparation. The information is stored in the digital software where all the coronal anatomical details are preserved without any modifications. The scanned designs are then applied to the scanned teeth preparations, sent to the milling machine and milled into full-contour clear acrylic resin burn-out patterns. The acrylic resin patterns are tried in the patient's mouth the same day to verify the full seating of the PRDP components. The patterns are then invested and cast into gold crowns and cemented in the conventional manner.</AbstractText>
          <CopyrightInformation>© 2016 by the American College of Prosthodontists.</CopyrightInformation>
        </Abstract>
        <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>El Kerdani</LastName>
            <ForeName>Tarek</ForeName>
            <Initials>T</Initials>
            <AffiliationInfo>
              <Affiliation>Department of Restorative Dental Sciences, Division of Prosthodontics, University of Florida College of Dentistry, Gainesville, FL.</Affiliation>
            </AffiliationInfo>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Roushdy</LastName>
            <ForeName>Sally</ForeName>
            <Initials>S</Initials>
            <AffiliationInfo>
              <Affiliation>Department of Restorative Dental Sciences, Division of Prosthodontics, University of Florida College of Dentistry, Gainesville, FL.</Affiliation>
            </AffiliationInfo>
          </Author>
        </AuthorList>
        <Language>eng</Language>
        <PublicationTypeList>
          <PublicationType UI="D002363">Case Reports</PublicationType>
          <PublicationType UI="D016428">Journal Article</PublicationType>
        </PublicationTypeList>
        <ArticleDate DateType="Electronic">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>08</Month>
          <Day>02</Day>
        </ArticleDate>
      </Article>
      <MedlineJournalInfo>
        <Country>United States</Country>
        <MedlineTA>J Prosthodont</MedlineTA>
        <NlmUniqueID>9301275</NlmUniqueID>
        <ISSNLinking>1059-941X</ISSNLinking>
      </MedlineJournalInfo>
      <ChemicalList>
        <Chemical>
          <RegistryNumber>7440-57-5</RegistryNumber>
          <NameOfSubstance UI="D006046">Gold</NameOfSubstance>
        </Chemical>
      </ChemicalList>
      <CitationSubset>D</CitationSubset>
      <MeshHeadingList>
        <MeshHeading>
          <DescriptorName UI="D000368" MajorTopicYN="N">Aged</DescriptorName>
        </MeshHeading>
        <MeshHeading>
          <DescriptorName UI="D017076" MajorTopicYN="Y">Computer-Aided Design</DescriptorName>
        </MeshHeading>
        <MeshHeading>
          <DescriptorName UI="D003442" MajorTopicYN="Y">Crowns</DescriptorName>
        </MeshHeading>
        <MeshHeading>
          <DescriptorName UI="D000044" MajorTopicYN="N">Dental Abutments</DescriptorName>
        </MeshHeading>
        <MeshHeading>
          <DescriptorName UI="D017267" MajorTopicYN="Y">Dental Prosthesis Design</DescriptorName>
        </MeshHeading>
        <MeshHeading>
          <DescriptorName UI="D003832" MajorTopicYN="Y">Denture, Partial, Removable</DescriptorName>
        </MeshHeading>
        <MeshHeading>
          <DescriptorName UI="D006046" MajorTopicYN="N">Gold</DescriptorName>
        </MeshHeading>
        <MeshHeading>
          <DescriptorName UI="D006801" MajorTopicYN="N">Humans</DescriptorName>
        </MeshHeading>
        <MeshHeading>
          <DescriptorName UI="D008297" MajorTopicYN="N">Male</DescriptorName>
        </MeshHeading>
      </MeshHeadingList>
      <KeywordList Owner="NOTNLM">
        <Keyword MajorTopicYN="N">CADM</Keyword>
        <Keyword MajorTopicYN="N">cast gold</Keyword>
        <Keyword MajorTopicYN="N">milled acrylic resin patterns</Keyword>
      </KeywordList>
    </MedlineCitation>
    <PubmedData>
      <History>
        <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="accepted">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>06</Month>
          <Day>13</Day>
        </PubMedPubDate>
        <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="pubmed">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>8</Month>
          <Day>3</Day>
          <Hour>6</Hour>
          <Minute>0</Minute>
        </PubMedPubDate>
        <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="medline">
          <Year>2018</Year>
          <Month>5</Month>
          <Day>3</Day>
          <Hour>6</Hour>
          <Minute>0</Minute>
        </PubMedPubDate>
        <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="entrez">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>8</Month>
          <Day>3</Day>
          <Hour>6</Hour>
          <Minute>0</Minute>
        </PubMedPubDate>
      </History>
      <PublicationStatus>ppublish</PublicationStatus>
      <ArticleIdList>
        <ArticleId IdType="pubmed">27483086</ArticleId>
        <ArticleId IdType="doi">10.111pr.12525</ArticleId>
      </ArticleIdList>
    </PubmedData>
  </PubmedArticle>
  <PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="PubMed-not-MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
      <PMID Version="1">27483087</PMID>
      <DateCompleted>
        <Year>2018</Year>
        <Month>08</Month>
        <Day>07</Day>
      </DateCompleted>
      <DateRevised>
        <Year>2018</Year>
        <Month>08</Month>
        <Day>07</Day>
      </DateRevised>
      <Article PubModel="Print-Electronic">
        <Journal>
          <ISSN IssnType="Electronic">2326-5205</ISSN>
          <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Internet">
            <Volume>68</Volume>
            <Issue>11</Issue>
            <PubDate>
              <Year>2016</Year>
              <Month>11</Month>
            </PubDate>
          </JournalIssue>
          <Title>Arthritis &amp; rheumatology (Hoboken, N.J.)</Title>
        </Journal>
        <ArticleTitle>Reply.</ArticleTitle>
        <Pagination>
          <MedlinePgn>2826-2827</MedlinePgn>
        </Pagination>
        <ELocationID EIdType="doi" ValidYN="Y">10t.39831</ELocationID>
        <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Hitchon</LastName>
            <ForeName>Carol Ann</ForeName>
            <Initials>CA</Initials>
            <AffiliationInfo>
              <Affiliation>University of Manitoba, Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada.</Affiliation>
            </AffiliationInfo>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Koppejan</LastName>
            <ForeName>Hester</ForeName>
            <Initials>H</Initials>
            <AffiliationInfo>
              <Affiliation>Leiden University Medical Center, Leiden, The Netherlands.</Affiliation>
            </AffiliationInfo>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Trouw</LastName>
            <ForeName>Leendert A</ForeName>
            <Initials>LA</Initials>
            <AffiliationInfo>
              <Affiliation>Leiden University Medical Center, Leiden, The Netherlands.</Affiliation>
            </AffiliationInfo>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Huizinga</LastName>
            <ForeName>Tom J W</ForeName>
            <Initials>TJ</Initials>
            <AffiliationInfo>
              <Affiliation>Leiden University Medical Center, Leiden, The Netherlands.</Affiliation>
            </AffiliationInfo>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Toes</LastName>
            <ForeName>René E M</ForeName>
            <Initials>RE</Initials>
            <AffiliationInfo>
              <Affiliation>Leiden University Medical Center, Leiden, The Netherlands.</Affiliation>
            </AffiliationInfo>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>El-Gabalawy</LastName>
            <ForeName>Hani S</ForeName>
            <Initials>HS</Initials>
            <AffiliationInfo>
              <Affiliation>University of Manitoba, Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada.</Affiliation>
            </AffiliationInfo>
          </Author>
        </AuthorList>
        <Language>eng</Language>
        <GrantList CompleteYN="Y">
          <Grant>
            <GrantID>MOP‐77700</GrantID>
            <Agency>CIHR</Agency>
            <Country>Canada</Country>
          </Grant>
        </GrantList>
        <PublicationTypeList>
          <PublicationType UI="D016422">Letter</PublicationType>
          <PublicationType UI="D013485">Research Sup</PublicationType>
          <PublicationType UI="D016420">Comment</PublicationType>
        </PublicationTypeList>
        <ArticleDate DateType="Electronic">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>10</Month>
          <Day>09</Day>
        </ArticleDate>
      </Article>
      <MedlineJournalInfo>
        <Country>United States</Country>
        <MedlineTA>Arthritis Rheumatol</MedlineTA>
        <NlmUniqueID>101623795</NlmUniqueID>
        <ISSNLinking>2326-5191</ISSNLinking>
      </MedlineJournalInfo>
      <CommentsCorrectionsList>
        <CommentsCorrections RefType="CommentOn">
          <RefSource>dff</RefSource>
          <PMID Version="1">27483211</PMID>
        </CommentsCorrections>
        <CommentsCorrections RefType="CommentOn">
          <RefSource>Arthritis Rheumato</RefSource>
          <PMID Version="1">26946484</PMID>
        </CommentsCorrections>
      </CommentsCorrectionsList>
    </MedlineCitation>
    <PubmedData>
      <History>
        <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="received">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>07</Month>
          <Day>26</Day>
        </PubMedPubDate>
        <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="accepted">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>07</Month>
          <Day>28</Day>
        </PubMedPubDate>
        <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="pubmed">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>10</Month>
          <Day>28</Day>
          <Hour>6</Hour>
          <Minute>0</Minute>
        </PubMedPubDate>
        <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="medline">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>10</Month>
          <Day>28</Day>
          <Hour>6</Hour>
          <Minute>1</Minute>
        </PubMedPubDate>
        <PubMedPubDate PubStatus="entrez">
          <Year>2016</Year>
          <Month>8</Month>
          <Day>3</Day>
          <Hour>6</Hour>
          <Minute>0</Minute>
        </PubMedPubDate>
      </History>
      <PublicationStatus>ppublish</PublicationStatus>
      <ArticleIdList>
        <ArticleId IdType="pubmed">27483087</ArticleId>
        <ArticleId IdType="doi">efre</ArticleId>
      </ArticleIdList>
    </PubmedData>
  </PubmedArticle>
</PubmedArticleSet>
```

Kindly help me out on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: If you want to read an XML file, and then parse its contents, you are probably better off using a purpose-built XML parser, rather than Tika.

There are various options - each with its own pros and cons (for example speed, memory consumption).

Here is one approach - it reads the entire file into memory, but you already do that with your Tika approach, so I assume file size is not a problem.

The code assumes there is a file called `pubmed.xml` which contains the XML presented in the question.

It reads the XML from file, and handles each element as a DOM node.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

...

public void parseUsingDom() {
    try {

        File xmlFile = new File("C:/tmp/pubmed.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList articles = doc.getElementsByTagName("Article");
        for (int i = 0; i < articles.getLength(); i++) {
            Node article = articles.item(i);
            if (article.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element articleElement = (Element) article;

                String title = articleElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("ArticleTitle")
                        .item(0).getTextContent();
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Title  : " + title);

                NodeList authors = articleElement.getElementsByTagName("Author");
                for (int j = 0; j < authors.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node author = authors.item(j);
                    if (author.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element authorElement = (Element) author;

                        String foreName = authorElement
                                .getElementsByTagName("ForeName")
                                .item(0).getTextContent();
                        String lastName = authorElement
                                .getElementsByTagName("LastName")
                                .item(0).getTextContent();
                        System.out.println("Author : " + lastName + ", " + foreName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    }
}
```

The program prints the following output, just as a demo of what is possible:

```
Title  : The Use of CADCAM Technology for Fabricating Cast Gold Survey Crowns under Existing Partial Removable Dental Prosthesis. A Clinical Report.
Author : El Kerdani, Tarek
Author : Roushdy, Sally

Title  : Reply.
Author : Hitchon, Carol Ann
Author : Koppejan, Hester
Author : Trouw, Leendert A
Author : Huizinga, Tom J W
Author : Toes, René E M
Author : El-Gabalawy, Hani S
```

In your case, you would capture the relevant values in a hash map, of course.

Comment: I have solved this by XSLT approach where i parse my custom xml using xslt and convert my custom xml directly to solr understandable form. https://medium.com/@akshayt030/index-custom-xml-in-solr-using-solrj-api-ea362f17cba7

Comment: @Akoffice That's great - perhaps you can add that as an answer, here (not just the link but the details of the solution). If that is the most helpful answer, you can also accept your own answer!